# 2 Laravel Projects for the Same Domain

Tags: laravel, apache

I have two Laravel projects as desktop and adaptive. I want to use the same domain (ex: xyz.com) for both projects and I don't know how to configure the apache.

If User-agent is mobile then it should go to adaptive project, otherwise it should go to desktop.

I did lots of search but I couldn't find a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use subdomain ?

```
Route::domain('{account}.myapp.com')->group(function () {
    Route::get('user/{id}', function ($account, $id) {
        //
    });
});
```

Comment: Using subdomains has some drawbacks, so I just want to use single domain. Thanks :)